# Angular RxJS: two nested https and update component when first one is reach

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I need to perform two http requests. One after first one, since values provided by first one are going to be used to make the other http calls.

I also **need to update my component when first http** is resolved. And **also, updated it when second http is also resolved**.

```
interface Vehicle {
    readonly id: string;
    readonly name: string;
    readonly brand: string;
}
```

First http call is getting `name`, and the other one the `brand`.

Guess this html component:

```
<div *ngFor='let vehicle of vehicles$ | async'>
    {{vehicle.name}} - {{vehicle.brand}}
</div>
```

In controller:

```
vehicles$: Observable<Array<Vehicle>>
ngOnInit() {
    this.vehicles$ = this._vehicleService.getVehicles();
    // how to go on???
}
```

where `getVehicles`:

```
getVehicles(): Observable<Array<Vehicle>> {
    return http.get("url")
        .map(vehicle => <Vehicle>{id: vehicle.id, name: vehicle.name});
}

getVehicleBrand(ids: Array<String>): Observable<Array<VehicleBrand>> {
   // build url according ids parameter
   return http.get("url")
       .map(brand => <VehicleBrand>{id: brand.vehicle_id, brand.name});
}
```

How could I merge `Vehicle` with `VehicleBrand`?

Comment: Just to check, `getVehicleBrand()` will be called right after `getVehicles()`?

Comment: Yes, since `getVehicleBrand()` needs `getVehicles()` responses `vehicle.id`...

Comment: `getVehicles()` doesnt have any parameters, but you call it `getVehicles(["1", "2"])`. So it doesn't make sense. For me it is not clear what your endpoints expects, so would be helpful if you provide that - what type they take and what type they return. Otherwise, IMO to answer this is more like guessing

Comment: Sorry. Solved ;)

Answer (score 1):

Merging data between requests shouldn't be the responsibility of the component.
That's what services are for.

Example of what such a service might look (feel free to customize it according to your own needs of course):

```
const vehiclesIdNameMock: VehicleIdName[] = [
  { id: 'vehicle-1', name: 'Vehicle 1' },
  { id: 'vehicle-2', name: 'Vehicle 2' },
  { id: 'vehicle-3', name: 'Vehicle 3' },
];

const vehiclesIdToBrandMap: { [key: string]: VehicleIdBrand } = {
  'vehicle-1': { id: 'vehicle-1', brand: 'Brand A' },
  'vehicle-2': { id: 'vehicle-2', brand: 'Brand A' },
  'vehicle-3': { id: 'vehicle-3', brand: 'Brand B' },
}

@Injectable()
export class VehiclesService {
  private getVehiclesIdName(): Observable<VehicleIdName[]> {
    return of(vehiclesIdNameMock).pipe(delay(500));
  }

  private getVehicleIdBrand(id: string): Observable<VehicleIdBrand> {
    return of(vehiclesIdToBrandMap[id]).pipe(delay(500));
  }

  public getVehicles(): Observable<Vehicle[]>{
    return this.getVehiclesIdName().pipe(
      mergeMap(vehiclesIdName => {
        const requests: Observable<VehicleIdBrand>[] = vehiclesIdName.map(vehicleIdName => this.getVehicleIdBrand(vehicleIdName.id))

        return forkJoin(requests).pipe(
          map(vehiclesIdBrand => vehiclesIdBrand.map(
            (vehiclesIdBrand, index) => ({ ...vehiclesIdBrand, ...vehiclesIdName[index] })
          ))
        );
      })
    )
  }
}
```

The 2 private methods here are mocked because I obviously don't have access to your endpoint but as long as your return the same data type that'll be fine.

Then your VehicleComponent would be as clean as:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-vehicles',
  templateUrl: './vehicles.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./vehicles.component.css']
})
export class VehiclesComponent {
  public vehicles$: Observable<Vehicle[]> = this.vehiclesService.getVehicles();

  constructor(private vehiclesService: VehiclesService) {}
}
```

Here's a live demo on Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-et3oug

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```js
http.get("url").pipe(
    map(vehicle => <Vehicle>{id: vehicle.id, name: vehicle.name})
    tap(vehicle => { this.vehicles$.next(vehicle); })
    switchMap(vehicle => this.getVehicleBrand([vehicle.id]));
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async` `await` here is the example.

**Controller**

```
vehicles$: Observable<Array<Vehicle>>
ngOnInit() {
      this.getVehicle(); 
}

async getVehicle() {
    this.vehicles$ = this._vehicleService.getVehicles(["1", "2"]);
    await getVehicleBrand([vehicalIds]);
    // other code
}

getVehicleBrand(ids: Array<String>): Observable<Array<VehicleBrand>> {
return new Promise(resolve => { 
   // build url according ids parameter
   http.get("url")
       .map(brand => <VehicleBrand>{id: brand.vehicle_id, brand.name});
    resolve();
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return observables in a sequential manner, you can make use of RxJS's [mergeMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) to map over the observable values from the service's `getVehicles()` into an inner observable, to get the list of ids. Then, we call the `getVehicleBrand()` method from the service, and the observables are returned in subscribe() on the subsequent line.

From there, you can match the brand name with the respective vehicles.

On your component.ts, this is how it will look like

```
ngOnInit() {
  this._vehicleService.getVehicles(["1", "2"]).pipe(
    mergeMap(vehicles => {
      const vehicleIdList: string[] = vehicles.map(vehicle => vehicle.id);
      return this._vehicleService.getVehicleBrand(vehicleIdList);
    })
  ).subscribe(res => {
    // continue the rest
  })
}
```

Comment: I miss here some code in order to get component is updated when `getVehicles` is resolved...

Comment: @Jordi Sorry, you mean something like updating `this.vehicles`? Such that each object within `vehicles` contain the brand name as well?