# How to create a new Observable array based on two existing Observable arrays,

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have two Observable arrays being populated from different API endpoints.  What I want to do is compare them based on the ID, so only take where equal, then cherry pick properties from each object within the arrays to produce a new Observable array. Any ideas?

Comment: you can use `forkjoin` for the same

Comment: I've answered a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56271507/2398593

Comment: @maxime1992 (fun, I'm a Maxime from 1993 :D) your answer lacks some features, such as undefined protection and same IDs filtering !

Comment: Ha, fun one. Filtering undefined should be trivial and same IDs filtering should be easy too but I can give a shot on your particular issue. Could you try to be more precise in what your want exactly and maybe try to make a minimal repro on stackblitz?

Answer (score 1):

This should do :

```
forkJoin(
  obs1$,
  obs2$,
).pipe(
  map((obs1, obs2) => 
    obs1
      .filter(v1 => obs2.some(v2 => v1.id === v2.id))
      .map((v, i, a) => ({ ...v, ...(obs2[i] || {})}))
  ),
);
```

- Combine both observables
- pipe to map
- filter the first array on the equal IDs of the second array
- map the item of the first array to be extended by the item of the second array (if defined)
- Return the value created from the pipe.

Proof of concept :

```js
const d1 = [
  { id: 1, value: 'v1.1' },
  { id: 2, value: 'v1.2' },
  { id: 3, value: 'v1.3' },
  { id: 4, value: 'v1.4' },
];

const d2 = [
  { id: 1, value: 'v1.1 overriden' },
  { id: 2, value2: 'v1.2 extended' },
];

console.log(d1
  .filter(v1 => d2.some(v2 => v1.id === v2.id))
  .map((v, i, a) => ({ ...v, ...(d2[i] || {})}))
);
```

Comment: Perfect answer :)

Comment: thanks for the anaswer but .some doesnt appear to work with observables

Comment: @Arnold.Krumins you have the live proof it does. Try following the answer **letter by letter** and it should work. Otherwise, it means you haven' two arrays.

Comment: No I have  LatestReadings$: Observable<Measurement[]>; so not arrays as such,

Answer (score 0):

```
forkJoin(
      this.MeasuringPoints$,
      this.LatestReadings$,
    ).subscribe( data => {
          .filter(v1 =>  data[1].some(v2 => v1.uuid === v2.mpUuid))
          .map((v, i) => ({ ...v, ...(data[1][i] || {})}));
    });
```

Comment: @Maryannah thanks for you help. I had to subscribe to get access to the data.